# Getting a set of random number between 2 numbers that have a certain mean.

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, random

Problem: Getting a set of random numbers between two values that will have a certain mean value.

Let say we getting n number of random number  where the number will be between 1 and 100. We have a mean of 25.

My first approach is to have 2 modes where we have aboveMean and belowMean where the  first random number is the initial range 1 and 100. Every subsequent number will check the total sum. If the total sum is above the mean, we go to case aboveMean which is then get a random number between 1 and 25. If the total sum is below the mean, we do case belowMean then get a random number between 26 and 100.

I need some idea on how to approach this problem beside the crude get a random number to add it to the total then get the average. If it above the mean in question, we get a random number below the mean and so forth. While it does work, doesn't seem to be the best method.

I'm guessing I should brush up on probability to approach this random number generator.

Comment: Fairly sure this is duped..

Comment: ..but I can't find it:(

Comment: Duped? As in there someone else have this question? I tried to look for it.

Comment: *Every subsequent number will check the total sum. If the total sum is above the mean, we go to case aboveMean* **Note:** `total sum` is always `above the mean` after `i = 1`.

Comment: @AntoJurković : Good link, but not directly translatable to C++.

Comment: What is missing here is OP needs to detail the type of asymmetric distribution wanted.  Else `width =min(avg-minvalue,maxvalue-avg)*2; rand()%width - width/2 + avg` will do the meet OP's technical requirements, but likely not the intent.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what the question is asking. There's a method "which does work" in the question, but as described the random sample won't have the desired M in general, nor will the expected value of the average (which is a possible interpretation of the question) be M. It's also not clear what are acceptable distributions.

Comment: Consider a set of N numbers, the first N-1 being _random_ in the range [1 100] and happen to have a average of 25.  Now which is more important: "have a certain mean.", in which case, the Nth number generated is not random (it must be 25 to maintain the average) OR the 10th number is also random and then the final average is not certainly 25?  These completing goals need more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Let us divide the range into left and right portions.  Use a value from the portion at a frequency corresponding to the relative width of the other half.

```
int Leruce_rand(int min, int mean, int max) {
  int r = rand()%(max - min + 1);
  if (r < mean) {
    // find number in right half
    return rand()%(max - mean + 1) + mean;
  } else {
    // find number in left half
    return rand()%(mean - min) + min;
  }
```

Assumes `mean` is part of the right half.  This quick solution likely has small bias.

Given OP's values, roughly, the average of the left half is 12.5 and called 75% of the time.  Average of the right is 62.5 called 25% of the time: average 25.

---

This approach differs from OP's which "Every subsequent number will check the total sum. If the total sum is above the mean, we go to case aboveMean which is then get a random number between 1 and 25." As that absolutely prevents a set of occurrences above or below the mean.  With RNG, the value generated should *not* be biased on the history of previous generated values.

Comment: This has E(average) = M, but it's ambiguous in the question whether they want a sample with average=M (like in the mathoverflow link given in the comments above), or the expected average to be M.

Comment: @Paul Hankin Agreed, so I tried to state my understanding of the unclear givens.  ;-) When presented with incomplete info I am reminded that there are 2 types of people in the world: 1) Those who can draw conclusions from incomplete data.

Comment: "Getting a set of random numbers" sounds pretty unambiguous to me -- the above just gives one number and not a set.

Comment: @Soren Agree "Getting a set of random number(s) between 2 numbers" is clear.  Yet OP adds more.  "Getting a set of random number between 2 numbers that have a certain mean." is less clear as "have a certain mean" imposes a restriction on the random numbers in an unclear manor.  Is that the set must have that mean (and so the numbers are _not_ independently random) or the mean of the set of numbers tends to be the desired mean (25)?

Comment: Unlike my (downvoted and now edited) answer, this gives an (almost) even distribution of numbers < 25 and a smaller (almost) even distribution of numbers >= 25. What I like is that the range of each number generated is not biased by (and so not predictable from) the current mean.

Comment: Putting your function into my program, gave a mean of `24.997494`

Answer (score 0):

There's literally an infinite number of ways to achieve this. For instance, generate 3 random numbers between 1 and 100 (`std::uniform_int_distribution`) and take the minimum of those (`std::min(a,b,c)`).

Obviously, for a mean of 75 you'll need to pick the *maximum* of 3 numbers.

The benefit of this method is that each outcome is *independent* of the previous ones. It's *completely* random.

Comment: It's a neat trick for the specific example mentioned in the question, but isn't the mean of this random variable 25.5025 rather than 25?

Comment: Close enough for me ;) I dont recall the exact figures; I might have used 0 as lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

Take some good distribution and use it. Say, [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). Use `B(99,24/99)`,
so sampled values are in the range 0...99, with parameter `p` equal to 24/99.

So if you have routine which sample from B, then all you need is to add 1 
to be in he range 1...100

Mean value for binomial would be `p*n`, in this case equal to 24. Because you're adding 1, your mean value would be 25 as required. C++11 has binomial RNG in the
standard library

Some code (not tested)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::binomial_distribution<int> distribution(99, double(24)/double(99));

    for (int i=0; i != 1000; ++i) {
        int number = distribution(generator) + 1;
        std::cout << number << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume a fair `random(a,b)` function (this question should not be about which random function is better) then simply just restrcting ithe ranges that is piced from should be a good start, like;

```
const int desiredCount = 16;
const int deiredMean = 25;
int sumValues = random(a,b);
int count = 1;

while (count < desriredCount - 1) {
     int mean = sumValue/count;
     int nextValue = 0;
     if (mean < desiredMean) // Too small, reduce probablity of smaller numbers
          nextValue = random(a+(desiredMean-mean)/(desriredCount-count),b);
     else //too large, reduce probability of larger numbers
          nextValue = random(a,b-(mean-desiredMean)/(desriredCount-count));
     sumValue += nextValue;
     count += 1;
}
int lastValue = desiredMean*desriredCount - sumValue/count;
sumValue += lastValue;
count += 1;
```

**Note**: The above is not tested, and my thinking is that the trimming of the upper and lower bound may not be sufficently aggressive to do the trick, but I hope that i will get you going.

Some boundary conditions, such as if you only want 2 numbers and a means of 25 from numbers between 0 and 100, the initial random number cannot be larger than 50, since that makes it impossible to pick the second (last) number -- so if you want the algo to give you exact mean values under all circumstances, then a bit more tweaking is needed.

Comment: How are you passing values to a function that takes none? `long int random(void);`

Comment: @David C. Rankin `random()` is not a standard C function.  "Assume a fair `random(a,b)` function" is a reasonable staring point.

Comment: That's the missing piece of the puzzle. It was more an actual curiosity.

Comment: This approach will meet the average requirement given the `if (mean < desiredMean)` test, yet that defeats the randomness.  The number generated should not be biased based on the _history_ of the running mean.

Comment: If you want a specific mean, say 25 from numbers [0..100] then there will always be a bias in the randomness, since you are not free to choose from the entire range [0..100] at random -- partial factoring in the running mean is probably the best way of allowing as much randomness in a series as possible, since the final mean is an important success criteria

Answer (score 0):

OP's wants a *set* of numbers meeting certain criteria.

Consider generating *all* possible sets of `n` numbers in the range `[min max]` and then eliminating all sets but those with the desired `mean`.  Now randomly select one of those sets.  This would meet OP's goal and IMO would pass fair randomness tests.  Yet this direct approach is potentially a huge task.

Alternatively, randomly generate lots of sets until one is found that meets the *mean* test.

The below meets OP's requirement of a specified mean without *directly* biasing the random numbers selected.  Certainly not an *efficient* method when the desired `mean` is far from the `min/max` average.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void L_set(int *set, size_t n, int min, int mean, int max) {
  assert(n > 0);
  assert(min >= 0);
  assert(mean >= min);
  assert(max >= mean);

  size_t i;
  long long diff;
  long long sum_target = n;
  unsigned long long loop = 0;
  sum_target *= mean;
  int range = max - min + 1;
  do {
    loop++;
    long long sum = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      set[i] = rand() % range + min;
      sum += set[i];
    }
    diff = sum_target - sum;  // What does the final number need to be?
  } while (diff < min || diff > max);  
  set[0] = (int) diff;

  printf("n:%zu min:%d mean:%2d max:%3d loop:%6llu {", n, min, mean, max, loop);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%3d,", set[i]);
  }
  printf("}\n");
  fflush(stdout);
}

int main(void) {
  int set[1000];
  L_set(set, 10, 1, 2, 4);
  L_set(set, 16, 1, 50, 100);
  L_set(set, 16, 1, 25, 100);
  L_set(set, 16, 1, 20, 100);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
n:10 min:1 mean: 2 max:  4 loop:     1 {  4,  2,  4,  3,  2,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,}
n:16 min:1 mean:50 max:100 loop:     2 { 45, 81, 24, 50, 93, 65, 70, 52, 28, 91, 25, 36, 21, 45, 11, 63,}
n:16 min:1 mean:25 max:100 loop:  3257 { 52,  1, 15, 70, 66, 30,  1,  4, 26,  1, 16,  4, 48, 42, 19,  5,}
n:16 min:1 mean:20 max:100 loop:192974 { 24, 10, 13,  3,  3, 53, 22, 12, 29,  1,  7,  6, 90, 11, 20, 16,}
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** this generates numbers in the range 1..100 with a theoretical mean of 25.25. It does this by using a random modulus in the range 1..100. Note that the required mean is 25, which is not exactly a quarter of the range 1..100.

OP wanted a way of varying the next number chosen according to whether the mean is less than or more than 25, but that lends some predictabilty - if the mean is more than 25 then you know the next "random" number will be less than 25.

The random calculation in the code is a very simple one line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define RUNS 10000000
#define MAXN 100

int main() {
    int n, i, sum = 0, min = MAXN, max = 0;
    int freq[MAXN+1] = {0};
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < RUNS; i++) {
        n = 1 + rand() % (1 + rand() % 100);        // average modulus is (1 + MAX) / 2
        if(max < n) {
            max = n;                                // check that whole range is picked
        }
        if(min > n) {
            min = n;
        }
        freq[n]++;                                  // keep a tally
        sum += n;
    }

    // show statistis
    printf("Mean = %f, min = %d, max = %d\n", (double)sum / RUNS, min, max);
    for(n = MAXN; n > 0; n--) {
        printf("%3d ", n);
        for(i = (freq[n] + 5000) / 10000; i > 0; i--) {
            printf("|");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output showing distribution / 10000:

```
Mean = 25.728128, min = 1, max = 100
100
 99
 98
 97
 96 |
 95 |
 94 |
 93 |
 92 |
 91 |
 90 |
 89 |
 88 |
 87 |
 86 ||
 85 ||
 84 ||
 83 ||
 82 ||
 81 ||
 80 ||
 79 ||
 78 |||
 77 |||
 76 |||
 75 |||
 74 |||
 73 |||
 72 |||
 71 ||||
 70 ||||
 69 ||||
 68 ||||
 67 ||||
 66 ||||
 65 ||||
 64 |||||
 63 |||||
 62 |||||
 61 |||||
 60 |||||
 59 |||||
 58 ||||||
 57 ||||||
 56 ||||||
 55 ||||||
 54 ||||||
 53 ||||||
 52 |||||||
 51 |||||||
 50 |||||||
 49 |||||||
 48 |||||||
 47 ||||||||
 46 ||||||||
 45 ||||||||
 44 ||||||||
 43 |||||||||
 42 |||||||||
 41 |||||||||
 40 |||||||||
 39 ||||||||||
 38 ||||||||||
 37 ||||||||||
 36 ||||||||||
 35 |||||||||||
 34 |||||||||||
 33 |||||||||||
 32 ||||||||||||
 31 ||||||||||||
 30 ||||||||||||
 29 |||||||||||||
 28 |||||||||||||
 27 |||||||||||||
 26 ||||||||||||||
 25 ||||||||||||||
 24 ||||||||||||||
 23 |||||||||||||||
 22 |||||||||||||||
 21 ||||||||||||||||
 20 ||||||||||||||||
 19 |||||||||||||||||
 18 |||||||||||||||||
 17 ||||||||||||||||||
 16 |||||||||||||||||||
 15 |||||||||||||||||||
 14 ||||||||||||||||||||
 13 |||||||||||||||||||||
 12 ||||||||||||||||||||||
 11 |||||||||||||||||||||||
 10 ||||||||||||||||||||||||
  9 |||||||||||||||||||||||||
  8 ||||||||||||||||||||||||||
  7 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||
  6 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
  5 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
  4 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
  3 |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
  2 ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
  1 ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

OP did not state what kind of distribution was wanted, for example two straight lines pivoting at 25, or perhaps equal distribution each side of 25. However this solution is very simple to implement.

Comment: I'm a tad confuse. This seem have a very small standard deviation less than 10ish.  I'm kind of confused about the rand() line. Never mind, I understand the code a bit more. My bad.

Comment: You will only get a mean of exactly 25 if *every* random number is 25, which is not random. This randomises the modulus too, so that more numbers come out below 25 (a quarter of the range) than above. Because the average modulus is 50, giving an average final random rumber of 25.

Comment: The deviation is small because I made a lot of runs to average each session. Those are not 3 random numbers: they are the averge of each session, seeing as you want to see a mean of 25.

Comment: Yea, I realized. Took me a min to understand that line a bit .

Answer (score -1):

you have to go into some probabilities theory. there are a lot of methods to judge on random sequence. for example if you lower the deviation you will get triangle-looking-on-a-graph sequence, which can in the end be proven not trully random. so there is not really much choice than getting random generator and discarding the sequences you don't like.